# Deploy War File in Microsoft IIS 7

Tags: java, iis-7, war

I would like to ask how can I deploy a war file to Microsoft IIS 7?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't. You need a Java EE Web Container such as Tomcat or JBoss in order to do so. IIS can just act as a front facing proxy for the stuff hosted through the WAR file.

What you probably need is a way to connect IIS and Tomcat together so that requests for any *dynamic* resources such as JSPs and Servlets can be delegated to Tomcat.

The following link explains how to do so in detail.

http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html

Comment: I had an idea to run tomcat seperadly, start my servlet and send a redirect from my website (using javascript) to that servlet, it should work even without creating any connectino between tomcat and iis, no?

Comment: You wanted to use IIS, so I told you how to do it. If you don't want to use IIS, servlets still work fine.

Comment: OK, i just thought that initialy the iis will be capable to run java code, but if it doesn't so i think it is easier to just install tomcat seperadly from the iis and run both of them togheter

Answer (score 4):

Please read this article: [Deploying Java Servlet applications on Windows with IIS](http://www.helicontech.com/articles/deploying-java-servlet-applications-on-windows-with-iis/) The Java is running on Jetty and IIS is used as a proxy, but in this solution all components are fit together to make it look and feel like it is built-in IIS feature of running WAR files.