# How to deploy java (jar or war) onto Windows IIS

Tags: java, iis

I have a java project that runs its own server (localhost) for users to access. I was then asked to deploy my tool in Apache so I wrapped it in a WAR file (along with some changes to create servlets) and that is what we are using now. However, I now need to deploy my app onto a Windows IIS server. Does anyone know of how to do this? Whats needs to be rewritten or modified, or is the only answer (found on another question) to install tomcat and have IIS talk to tomcat? Thank you very much

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391826/deploy-war-file-in-microsoft-iis-7

Comment: Hi @Daniel G, have you tired my answer ?

Answer (score 4):

Try this: [Deploying WAR files on IIS](http://www.helicontech.com/articles/deploying-java-servlet-applications-on-windows-with-iis/)

Answer (score 1):

This may be useful to you - http://tomcatiis.riaforge.org/

Answer (score -4):

It is very simple Process. Just follow the following steps. ( Version 5.5.25 )

1. Open Tomcat in Browser using http://tomcat-address(network ip or localhost) 
   It will open tomcat's page.
2. From the left side's Administration part click on the Tomcat Manager link.
   It will ask for the user-name and password. Supply the admin user-name password. In generat case it is "admin" and blank, means no password. After it will show you the list of the currently installed war files.
3. Now go to Deploy section after the installed war application's list.
4. There will be section of `WAR file to deploy` , click on choose file to select your .war file.
5. Now click on Deploy Button and its done.

Comment: Please read the Question ! It says :
How to deploy java (jar or war) "onto Windows IIS"


But not tomcat. 
You are answering to deploy a war in tomcat.