# Java JVM versus Glassfish

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I'm really new to Java and I have a basic question.  I'm getting ready to deploy a Java web service that I have created in Netbeans/Glassfish.  I used Netbeans because of the development GUI and tools.  Of course I also deployed to Netbean's built in GF server because of easy and simplicity.  I have a Windows 8 server with IIS that I now need to deploy this to.  I was thinking that since Java 1.7 EE was already on my IIS server, than I wouldn't need a "container server" like GF but that doesn't appear to be the case.  So, I'm confused.  What's the difference between the server that Glassfish creates and the JVM that Java EE creates when it is installed?  If I have to install Glassfish on my IIS server, am I going to have competing web services and port conflicts to resolve?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you confusing Java SE and Java EE?

Comment: How is Java 1.7 EE in your IIS server? What exactly did you install?

Comment: JavaEE is the api reference which can be implemented by different vendors, Glassfish is an actual implementation of a JavaEE application server by Oracle.

Comment: Yes, I probably am confusing EE with SE.  However don't both create a JVM to be able to run Java based applications?  No, I didn't install Java into IIS, it is just a JRE running along side and can be launched from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java Virtual Machine (JVM) is used to execute any Java program.  However, all it does is execute the byte code in a Java binary, for example a Java archive (.jar) file.  It does not include implementations of many of the Java EE libraries.

A web application, typically deployed as a web archive (.war) file, usually requires libraries not provided by the JVM.  In addition, the standard Java web application architecture means that the entry point for the application is not in the .war file - it is in the web application server, which then calls into the code provided in the .war file.

The web application server, which includes full J2EE containers like Glassfish and also more limited web servers like Tomcat and Jetty, acts as an intermediate layer, running on a JVM and executing the web application provided in the .war file.

Probably the best way to run your application on an IIS server is to set up the IIS server as the front end - so the client facing ports would be under IIS control - and set up the web server as a back end to which IIS forwards the relevant requests.  The answers at the following question provide some links that may be useful:

[Deploy War File in Microsoft IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391826/deploy-war-file-in-microsoft-iis-7)

Comment: Thank you Warren.  That was the clarification that I needed!  So if I understand you correctly, the JVM is to Glassfish what a VB/C# "VM" is to IIS.